# Почему массив первый раз проходит, а на второй начинает ругаться? [Python]

Tags: python

```
N = 452022
count = 0
while count !=5:
    de = []
    di = N // 2
    d = 2
    for d in range(2,di):
        if N % d == 0:
            de.append(d)
    M = (de[0] + de[-1])
    if M % 7 == 3:
        print(N, M)
        de = []
        count +=1
    N +=1
```

> ```
> M = (de[0] + de[-1])
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

Comment: ошибка говорит, что индекс массива некорректен, а это значит, что в данном случае `de` - пустой.

Comment: что нужно исправить в данном случае? Я попробовал перенести массив de = [] за цикл, но тогда ответ неверный

Comment: di у вас принимает значения только 0 и 1, и поэтому `range(2,di)` - тоже пустой.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Как это? Там же деление, а не остаток.

Comment: @GrAnd, да, ошибся.

Comment: Господа, расходимся. Я решил проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 N = 452022
 count = 0
 while count !=5:
     de = []
     di = N // 2
     for d in range(2,di+1):
         if N % d == 0:
             de.append(d)
         if len(de) > 1:
            M = (de[0] + de[-1])
            if M % 7 == 3:
            print(N,M)
            count +=1
 N +=1
```

Проблема была в том, что делитель, который идёт в массив может быть всего один. Поэтому нужно проверять количество делителей.

Comment: забыли удалить `d = 2`.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь поправил!